# DateTimeParseException - could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, date-parsing, java-time

I'm trying to parse the following date `"Wed, 26 Feb 2020 03:42:25 -0800"`

```
String datePattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);
```

But i get the following error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed, 26 Feb 2020 03:42:25 -0800'  
could not be parsed at index 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide a `Locale` that uses the language used by the date `String`. Otherwise, the formatter will take the system default locale.

See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    String dt = "Wed, 26 Feb 2020 03:42:25 -0800";
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dt, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US));
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
}
```

Output on my German system:

```
2020-02-26T03:42:25-08:00
```

Without this `Locale` (could be `UK`, too) I get the same `Exception` as you have got.

**Addition**
Good point given by @Lino: to be country-independent, better use `Locale.ENGLISH` because that keeps the respect to the language but doesn't depend on a specific `Locale` of a country or region.

Comment: `Locale.ENGLISH` will also work when one doesn't care about the country

Answer (score 2):

Don’t struggle with finding the right format pattern string and the right locale for your string. The formatter is built in.

```
    String dateStr = "Wed, 26 Feb 2020 03:42:25 -0800";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);

    System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2020-02-26T03:42:25-08:00

It works with `ZonedDateTime` too, but since `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` only handles offsets (such as offset amounts or GMT), not time zones, I found `OffsetDateTime` more appropriate.

`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` always expects day of week and month abbreviation in English, even no matter if you explicitly specify a different locale, because the RFC says that the string is in English. What could go wrong?